# Find $a^2-b^2+c^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be real numbers such that $ a−7b + 8c = 4$ and $8a + 4b−c = 7$. What is the value of $a^2 −b^2 + c^2$?

Comment: You only have 2 equations with 3 variables, so $a^2 - b^2 + c^2$ depends on a parameter $\lambda = c$. You can solve easily $a-7b = 4 - 8 \lambda$ and $8a + 4b = 7 + \lambda$ and, then, substitute in your goal expression: $a^2 - b^2 + c^2$.

Comment: Can I have reason for downvote

Comment: Yes, you do not show what you have tried so far. This is a good practise (or a *must*) in StackExchange's webs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first express $a$ and $b$ in terms of $c$. We have $a=4-8c+7b$, so we can substitute this to get $8(4-8c+7b)+4b-c=32-65c+60b=7$ so $b=\frac1{12}(-5+13c)$. We can now also see that $a=4-8c+7b=4-8c+\frac7{12}(-5+13c)$. Now we can substitute again to get $$a^2-b^2+c^2=(4-8c+\frac7{12}(-5+13c))^2-(\frac1{12}(-5+13c))^2+c^2$$ This we can work out, and you'll see that everything cancels out except one. So, the final answer should be $1$.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 2):

Given $a + 8c= 7b + 4$ and $8a - c = -4b + 7$

Now Squaring both equation, We get

$$a^2 + 64c^2 + 16ac= 49b^2 + 16 + 56b........(1)$$
$$64a^2 + c^2 - 16ac= 16b^2 + 49 - 56b........(2)$$

Summing these two equations gives

$$ 65a^2 + 65c^2 = 65b^2 + 65 \Rightarrow  a^2 - b^2 + c^2 = 1 $$.